# C# how to send a file via Telegram API

Tags: c#, telegram, wtelegramclient

I am using WTelegramClient library.

Here is how I send messages:

```
var client = new WTelegram.Client(Config);
await client.LoginUserIfNeeded();
var contacts = await client.Contacts_ImportContacts(new[]
{
   new InputPhoneContact { phone = "+998901234567" } 
});

if (contacts.imported.Length > 0)
await client.SendMessageAsync(contacts.users[contacts.imported[0].user_id], "Hello, world!");
```

How to send multiple files? or at least one file.

I need to send files from a list or from a folder. I will be glad for any help.

```
List<byte[]> file = new List<byte[]>();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sample from the official [documentation](https://github.com/wiz0u/WTelegramClient/blob/c93481189aefb3f1077efb00789ae21e3414a2c9/EXAMPLES.md#upload-a-media-file-and-post-it-with-caption-to-a-chat)

1.Get upload folder path, like this.

```
const string Filepath = @"C:\...\photo.jpg";
```

2.Upload file using client and path

```
var inputFile = await client.UploadFileAsync(Filepath);
```

3.Send file to peer (`chats.chats[ChatId]`)

```
await client.SendMediaAsync(peer, "Here is the photo", inputFile);
```

Sample code

```
const int ChatId = 1234567890; // the chat we want
const string Filepath = @"C:\...\photo.jpg";

using var client = new WTelegram.Client(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable);
await client.LoginUserIfNeeded();
var chats = await client.Messages_GetAllChats(null);
InputPeer peer = chats.chats[ChatId];
var inputFile = await client.UploadFileAsync(Filepath);
await client.SendMediaAsync(peer, "Here is the photo", inputFile);
```